# Edit posted sourcecode on wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress

I've a wordpress blog directly hosted from wordpress and I use the [code] tags to post sourcecode on wordpress, that works fine so far.

Thats the original code tag I posted

```
[code language="xml"]
 <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
[/code]
```

But when I try to edit my posts with contained sourcecode it looks like this

[image: new editet code]

and when I update my post the same not encoded symbols are shown on my blogpost too. Id don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to make sure the `Visual Mode` in WordPress is disabled, and only use `Text Mode`.

```
Users > Your Profile
```

Then you don't need to use a WordPress shortcode for adding a preformatted code block.

Check out the WordPress Codex **Writing Code in Your Posts** page:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts

Just use the HTML `<pre>` and `<code>` HTML tags:

```
 <pre><code>
    &lt;TypeScriptTarget&gt;ES5&lt;/TypeScriptTarget&gt;
 </pre></code>
```

You will notice I am using the HTML entity for the greater and less than symbols so they render correctly on the front-end of WordPress.

- `&lt;` =    <
- `&gt;` =    >

Resource links to the `<pre>` and `<code>` elements:

- `<pre>` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre
- `code` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Comment: the problem is, I am using wordpress.com and I am not selfhosting my blog.